# What does PARI mean by "showing all possibilites"?

Tags: sage, pari-gp

I am running this code, unfortunately I have no idea that why it is asking me a yes or no question.

```
 Normu(D) = my(k = bnfinit(y^2-D, 1), u = bnfunits(k)[1][1]); nfeltnorm(k, u); 
  {
    L = List();
    forprime (q = 5, 100,
      if (q%8==5, 
        N2 = Normu(q);
        forprime(p = q+1, 100,
          if(p%8==5,
            N1 = Normu(2*p);
            N3 = Normu(2*p*q);
            istput(L, [[q,p], [N1, N2, N3]])))));
  }
```

Unfortunately I can not undrestand what PARI means by 'showing all possibilities'and asks me to type(y or n).

I tried to change commands, and change the default PARI size, but not successful. I know the problem is not in the function defined above. I appreciate your help.

Update: I wrote all the code in one line and it is working but it doesn't consider internal 'if's
. It is not clear to me why it should work with this change.

```
    
 Normu(D) = my(k = bnfinit(y^2-D, 1), u = bnfunits(k)[1][1]); nfeltnorm(k, u); 
  {
    L = List();
    forprime (q = 5, 100, if (q%8==5, N2 = Normu(q);  forprime(p = q+1, 100, if(p%8==5, N1 = Normu(2*p); N3 = Normu(2*p*q); listput(L,[[q,p], [N1, N2, N3]])))));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message you're seeing `Display all ... possibilities? (y or n)` is produced by the `readline` library providing line editing to the `gp` binary. More precisely, it is the completion mechanism, triggered when pressing the `<TAB>` key. Presumably you used `<TAB>` character to indent your code, then copy-pasted it into a `gp` terminal. The "corrected" version works because you presumably removed all `<TAB>` characters when writing the program on a single line.

Try typing `<TAB>` at the `gp` prompt, you'll see the above message because `gp` is trying to complete the expression without any context, so there are lots of possibilities (all built-in and user functions, and all variables, and all operators). Since all possibilities can't be written down in a single screen of results, you're being asked if you really want to display all the possibilities; by typing `y` you'll be shown possible completions one screenful at a time.

Compare with `d<TAB>` for instance and you'll be shown all completion starting
by `d` (about 24 of them, no question this time since this fits into a single screen.

P.S. The original program has a typo in the final lines: `istput` instead of `listput`.